# Jenkins input pipeline step - Give submitter as local group

Tags: jenkins, input, jenkins-pipeline

I could find that “submitter” parameter accepts individual user IDs and external LDAP groups. But “Jenkins-local” groups defined by any authorization strategy are not working. 
Can you let me know if this is a known limitation or do I have to provide specific authorization to enable access for local groups?

Comment: I have the same requirement.  Based on my research, it looks like it may not be possible.  Seems silly to have to manually specify individual users.  When logged in to Jenkins visit the following page: https://jenkinshost/whoAmI/ .  I don't see any roles or groups listed for my user account even though they are assigned by the role strategy plugin.  If this page doesn't show role access, I doubt the input stage has access to this information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vadim. 
The workaround that I have used is define the comma separated list of individual users as a Jenkins global variable and manage the list from there. This gives a better maintainability. However, we end up duplicating groups.